# macintosh apcupsd startup not connecting to ups via snmp

Tags: macos, snmp

a while back i ran into a problem with osx and apcupsd, sometimes on reboot, osx would run apcupsd, and it would not connect to the ups via snmp.

the solution was to put a delay in a script file, to allow the ports to startup before apcupsd tried using them.

that was several years ago, and for the life of me, I cant find the original article detailing where that delay goes, I would appreciate anyone who could point me to the original article

Answer (score 0):

found it!!!

/usr/local/sbin/apcupsd-start

im happy now, and life is more complete

Comment: The phrasing seems to suggest that you are the author of the question. That would be OK, self answering is actually appreciated at StackOverflow. However, I do not see how this actually does answer the question. The question seems to ask for an online resource, an "article". The path here is a file path. I am confused.

Comment: Could you add how you had to edit the file to your answer? That would help other people in the future with the same issue.

Comment: when a mac boots up, it takes it a few to get the networking going and connected, if apcupsd runs before that happens, then it wont connect to the UPS, and will fail communications from there on, if you edit "/usr/local/sbin/apcupsd-start" on the mac, and put in /bin/sleep 128 right after the first line, it will delay starting up, until the networking has had a chance to fully get working, and that fixes the issue with apcupsd randomly not working on reboots.

Comment: Please [edit] to add the explanation from the comment to the answer. Also try to reduce to the answering part please, according to [answer]. And, just to end my confusion, are you or are you not the author of the question here?